# View with index causes Cannot insert duplicate key row on an update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I made a view that joins tables and made a clustered index on that view so that I can do full text searches on all the data I need from multiple tables. It works great, but I get Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.vPRs' with unique index 'IX_vPRs'. The duplicate key value is (47). error when this statement is run in a proc:

```
UPDATE prHdr
SET PRStatus=3
WHERE PrId=@prId
```

I don't understand why the update statement is inserting a row in the view (as the error explains).

Any ideas?

DEFINITIONS:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vPRs]
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT a.PrSeriesId,
       DivisionId [Division], 
       DateStart, 
       DateEnd, 
       Showroom, 
       VendorId, 
      VendName,
      PlmVendorId,
       b.Style, 
      e.Description [Status],
      f.FullName Requester,
        COUNT_BIG(*)AS countbig
FROM [dbo].[PrHdr] a
JOIN [dbo].[PrDtl] b ON a.prId=b.prId
JOIN dbo.PrSeries p ON a.PrSeriesId=p.PrSeriesId
JOIN [dbo].[PrStatus] e on a.PrStatusId = e.PrStatusId
JOIN [dbo].[User] f on p.UserCreate=f.UserName
GROUP BY a.PrSeriesId,
       DivisionId, 
       DateStart, 
       DateEnd, 
       Showroom, 
       VendorId, 
      VendName,
      PlmVendorId,
       b.Style, 
      e.Description,
      f.FullName

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_vPRs]    Script Date: 6/30/2014 10:45:49 PM ******/
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_vPRs] ON [dbo].[vPRs]
(
    [PrSeriesId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: So what's the definition of the view? Including index? Changing the value of a column involved in a join can certainly result in rows being added to the join result.

Comment: I edited OP with defintions

Comment: @MartinSmith You started to make me think about the join. Since I'm updating the status column and that status column is being used in a join, that change will cause another row in the view's query cause it's different from other related rows. So I added row id to view and used that for the index. Looks like i'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Indexed views materializes data as part of the view so that at query time it doesn't have to go to the underlying tables to get the values.

Looks like either the view definition is not right or the unique index denfintion is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with my attempt to add Indexes to a View in SQL Server 12.0.2000.8 (Azure DB). I wrote a schema bound view on a few tables, then added this Unique Clustered Index (as a prelude to adding a more useful index). Then I noticed that whenever I would make a change to an underlying table... I would get this error.

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.viewJobLaborBudget' with unique index 'ix_viewJobLaborBudget_Clustered'. The duplicate key value is (23-1627, 23-1627, 20).

Here is my index definition.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_viewJobLaborBudget_Clustered
    ON [dbo].[viewJobLaborBudget] (
       [projectNumber] DESC
       ,[docNumber] DESC
       ,[serviceOfferingID]
    );
```

I don't fully understand why this was happening... but I had a guess that its something to do with the db engine getting confused and trying to add another row to the index BEFORE removing the old one... assuming that its unable to just check existing and update. After several failed attempts to resolve this in different ways... I tried adding the [rowver] [rowversion] column from the main table to the index... because this will change every time the row is updated (and thus the view changed and index updated). Well... it worked!

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_viewJobLaborBudget_Clustered
    ON [dbo].[viewJobLaborBudget] (
       [projectNumber] DESC
       ,[docNumber] DESC
       ,[serviceOfferingID]
       ,[rowVer]
    );
```

Now I can update my tables over and over, and no error. Plus my view loads super fast!